# Is it possible to use on-prem compute machines or clusters to run Vertex AI?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I was wondering if I can use my local compute machine or cluster with Vertex AI to run my model training?

Comment: I hate to be pedantic... But of course it's *possible*... Google do it

Comment: The things that you can't do is to set up a custom training job on Vertex AI and use your local machine to run that training. Google Cloud Vertex AI can only use Google Cloud VM to run the container.

Answer (score 0):

You can run a container locally which also executes your training code the way it is trained in Vertex AI. You can follow this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/training/containerize-run-code-local#dependencies) regarding containerized and locally running training code.